# Move a table in landscape mode

Tags: tables, landscape

I have a table as below. I am unable to fit the table into a landscape page (I would like to increase the font to increase readability while its boundaries do not get close to the margins.) Moreover, I am unable to put the page number at the bottom of the page and make the rotated "Instance" cell to fit into its place (the cell at the top and left corner of the table.)

Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\newpage

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \scriptsize
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of the solution approaches based on the theoretical instances}
    \begin{tabular}{l|llllll|llllll|llllll|lll}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Instance}} & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{Mathematical programming}  & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{The NA-ACO algorithm}      & \multicolumn{6}{l|}{The heuristic algorithm}   & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP1 \\ (\%)}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP2 \\ (\%)}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP3 \\ (\%)}} \\ \cline{2-19}
          & Obj1  & Obj2  & Obj3  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)} & HPI   & FS\#  & Obj1  & Obj2  & Obj3  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}  & HPI   & FS\#  & Obj1  & Obj2  & Obj3  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}  & HPI   & FS\#  &       &       &  \\ \hline
    1     & 0.18  & 5.21  & 2.02  & 0.85  & 1     & 10    & 0.39  & 5.08  & 2.03  & 0.03  & 1     & 10    & 0.62  & 5.2   & 2     & 0.13  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 0     & 0.3 \\
    2     & 0     & 10.7  & 4     & 0.1   & 1     & 10    & 3.68  & 11.03 & 4     & 3.9   & 1     & 10    & 1.54  & 10.8  & 4     & 0.17  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 0.1   & 0 \\
    3     & 14.6  & 16.6  & 6     & 0.81  & 1     & 10    & 104.38 & 16.53 & 6.02  & 6.35  & 0.93  & 10    & 17.65 & 16.73 & 6     & 0.18  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 7.2   & 0 \\
    4     & 1130.81 & 29.64 & 9.83  & 7.6   & 0.87  & 10    & 1093.3 & 31.3  & 10.11 & 11.73 & 0.79  & 10    & 883.42 & 29.33 & 9.43  & 0.29  & 0.97  & 10    & 12.3  & 20.4  & 2.3 \\
    5     & 4267.77 & 49    & 12.43 & 21.23 & 1     & 10    & 2892.79 & 60.62 & 13.41 & 24.4  & 0.28  & 10    & 2505.25 & 54.88 & 12.67 & 0.73  & 0.93  & 10    & 0     & 72    & 6.5 \\
    6     & 6966.24 & 72.12 & 13.33 & 38.91 & 0.9   & 10    & 4010.66 & 99.81 & 17.11 & 58.33 & 0.09  & 10    & 2121.39 & 84.26 & 13.67 & 2.14  & 0.97  & 10    & 9.7   & 90.7  & 3 \\
    7     & 0.23  & 8.15  & 2.01  & 1.07  & 1     & 10    & 1.83  & 8.41  & 2.09  & 2.95  & 1     & 10    & 0.74  & 8.06  & 2     & 0.15  & 1     & 10    & 0.1   & 0.3   & 0.3 \\
    8     & 0.09  & 17.95 & 4.01  & 23.71 & 1     & 10    & 28.3  & 18.7  & 4.11  & 5.53  & 0.98  & 10    & 4.48  & 18.56 & 4     & 0.19  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 1.9   & 0.1 \\
    9     & 0.73  & 27.44 & 6.05  & 45.5  & 1     & 10    & 172.33 & 28.08 & 6.21  & 8.91  & 0.92  & 10    & 5.78  & 27.81 & 6     & 0.26  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 8.2   & 0 \\
    10    & 284.61 & 79.82 & 12.52 & 77.59 & 1     & 10    & 940.89 & 55.86 & 12.43 & 17.31 & 0.76  & 10    & 354.36 & 54.09 & 12    & 0.46  & 1     & 10    & 0.1   & 24.2  & 0 \\
    11    & 18594.44 & 129.64 & 15.99 & 77.27 & 0     & 10    & 2894.15 & 106.75 & 17.98 & 42.97 & 0.18  & 10    & 720.47 & 94.73 & 13.11 & 0.84  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.1  & 80.7  & 0 \\
    12    & 46281.17 & 179.85 & 17.63 & 91.87 & 0     & 10    & 5530.74 & 178   & 21.76 & 77.68 & 0.07  & 10    & 1558.86 & 144.23 & 14.24 & 1.26  & 0.99  & 10    & 98.9  & 91.6  & 0 \\
    13    & 7.54  & 13.61 & 2.09  & 12.68 & 1     & 10    & 20.77 & 14.23 & 2.52  & 4.07  & 0.95  & 10    & 6.96  & 13.98 & 2.06  & 0.19  & 0.98  & 10    & 0     & 4.2   & 1.9 \\
    14    & 744.81 & 50.74 & 5.14  & 64.83 & 0.63  & 10    & 343.69 & 28.7  & 5.51  & 8.16  & 0.79  & 10    & 92.07 & 27.15 & 4.85  & 0.35  & 0.99  & 10    & 36.2  & 19.9  & 0 \\
    15    & 1531.39 & 87.71 & 8.65  & 73.33 & 0.19  & 10    & 548.69 & 44.34 & 8.06  & 12.54 & 0.74  & 10    & 134.05 & 42.57 & 6.62  & 0.56  & 1     & 10    & 81.1  & 26    & 0 \\
    16    & 15248.51 & 170.71 & 23.32 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 1765.9 & 88.19 & 17.06 & 26.81 & 0.41  & 10    & 428.31 & 84.39 & 13.19 & 4.47  & 1     & 10    & 99.5  & 59    & 0 \\
    17    & 32220.52 & 308.6 & 22.36 & 115.42 & 0     & 10    & 3981.8 & 172.64 & 25.69 & 72.12 & 0.11  & 10    & 548.17 & 146.81 & 15.29 & 1.29  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.5  & 88    & 0 \\
    18    & 6091.59 & 1017.26 & 22.08 & 120   & 0.07  & 10    & 7420.12 & 287.26 & 32.11 & 120   & 0.04  & 10    & 843.87 & 219.56 & 16.28 & 2.53  & 1     & 10    & 92.7  & 95.6  & 0 \\
    19    & 53.38 & 19.77 & 7.5   & 2.68  & 1     & 10    & 111.41 & 19.71 & 7.29  & 5.49  & 0.96  & 10    & 44.14 & 19.95 & 7.51  & 0.23  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 3.8   & 0.1 \\
    20    & 215.55 & 38.87 & 15.24 & 15    & 1     & 10    & 651.13 & 38.6  & 15.47 & 11.84 & 0.78  & 10    & 182.17 & 38.11 & 15.11 & 0.33  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 21.8  & 0 \\
    21    & 567.37 & 60.71 & 23.34 & 48.1  & 1     & 10    & 1362.5 & 58.11 & 23.56 & 19.33 & 0.69  & 10    & 521.92 & 57.75 & 22.67 & 0.46  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 31    & 0 \\
    22    & 10838.22 & 327.13 & 51.96 & 120   & 0.2   & 10    & 2122.57 & 115.9 & 46.17 & 46.43 & 0.57  & 10    & 1347.86 & 114.95 & 45.36 & 1.02  & 1     & 10    & 80.1  & 42.7  & 0 \\
    23    & 57412.46 & 653.81 & 65.43 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 9046.97 & 231.64 & 77.07 & 116.57 & 0.05  & 10    & 3521.58 & 198.79 & 43.58 & 2.17  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.1  & 94.1  & 0 \\
    24    & 179789.2 & 885.03 & 92.67 & 120   & 0     & 9     & 15808.37 & 401.1 & 104.74 & 120   & 0.02  & 9     & 6025.15 & 334.02 & 48.43 & 6.04  & 0.98  & 10    & 99.11 & 97.11 & 0 \\
    25    & 19.94 & 24.13 & 8.27  & 4.63  & 1     & 10    & 110   & 24.28 & 8.44  & 6.71  & 0.92  & 10    & 7.44  & 24.3  & 8.24  & 0.26  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 7.8   & 0.1 \\
    26    & 101.52 & 48.45 & 16.71 & 52.98 & 1     & 10    & 782.48 & 48.92 & 17.4  & 16.34 & 0.74  & 10    & 77.16 & 49.35 & 16.78 & 0.41  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 26.2  & 0 \\
    27    & 2123.34 & 202.67 & 31.71 & 97.49 & 0.53  & 10    & 1586.7 & 74.26 & 26.7  & 27.12 & 0.6   & 10    & 245.94 & 75.41 & 25.65 & 0.61  & 1     & 10    & 46.6  & 40.4  & 0 \\
    28    & 39675.55 & 661.02 & 72.95 & 120   & 0.08  & 10    & 3990.52 & 153   & 51.41 & 61.91 & 0.5   & 10    & 1673.7 & 152.8 & 50    & 1.34  & 1     & 10    & 92.2  & 50.4  & 0 \\
    29    & 111545.7 & 989.78 & 98.33 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 10387.34 & 301.18 & 92.98 & 120   & 0.03  & 10    & 2303.83 & 261.1 & 47.56 & 2.9   & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 95.8  & 0 \\
    30    & 168626.5 & 1288.31 & 144.81 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 18672.19 & 517.85 & 130.56 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 3422.09 & 399.08 & 51.87 & 12.62 & 1     & 10    & 99.8  & 98.7  & 0 \\
    31    & 22.44 & 30.16 & 15.84 & 2.27  & 1     & 10    & 400.31 & 30.15 & 16.08 & 10.16 & 0.82  & 10    & 16.39 & 30.08 & 16.17 & 0.58  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 18    & 0 \\
    32    & 499   & 63.68 & 31.74 & 36.05 & 1     & 10    & 1514.82 & 61.12 & 30.35 & 20.58 & 0.69  & 10    & 230.41 & 63.12 & 32.05 & 0.96  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 31.3  & 0 \\
    33    & 1640.16 & 114.15 & 50.84 & 80.09 & 1     & 10    & 2977.32 & 91.89 & 47.89 & 32.54 & 0.61  & 10    & 1681.3 & 92.09 & 47.48 & 1.48  & 1     & 10    & 0.1   & 39.2  & 0 \\
    34    & 43656.29 & 912.92 & 115.96 & 120   & 0.4   & 10    & 7131.83 & 182.45 & 94.76 & 86.22 & 0.54  & 10    & 5276.55 & 183.18 & 93.82 & 3.86  & 1     & 10    & 60    & 46    & 0 \\
    35    & 172934.4 & 1285.11 & 178.8 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 16635.11 & 365.36 & 165.6 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 4371.41 & 314.36 & 84.42 & 4.69  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.1  & 97.4  & 0 \\
    36    & 252501.2 & 2665.97 & 258.28 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 29705.14 & 633.69 & 247.07 & 120   & 0.01  & 9     & 8521.68 & 496.41 & 95.59 & 12.53 & 0.97  & 10    & 97.4  & 98.89 & 0 \\
    37    & 0.39  & 39.72 & 17.41 & 3.28  & 1     & 10    & 551.69 & 39.75 & 17.88 & 15.17 & 0.77  & 10    & 12.21 & 39.49 & 17.34 & 0.38  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 23.2  & 0 \\
    38    & 289.29 & 155.34 & 38.45 & 74.93 & 0.99  & 10    & 1831.96 & 81.32 & 36.12 & 28.48 & 0.59  & 10    & 61.39 & 80.13 & 35.35 & 0.73  & 1     & 10    & 1.4   & 40.6  & 0 \\
    39    & 8222.3 & 752.47 & 97.57 & 118.37 & 0.28  & 10    & 3361.03 & 123.06 & 53.84 & 49.36 & 0.5   & 10    & 236.44 & 121.68 & 51.58 & 1.15  & 1     & 10    & 71.7  & 49.8  & 0 \\
    40    & 50211.12 & 1762.58 & 143.8 & 119.87 & 0     & 10    & 9195.09 & 246.92 & 108.61 & 119.97 & 0.05  & 10    & 1215.26 & 231.84 & 70.89 & 2.47  & 1     & 10    & 99.6  & 95    & 0 \\
    41    & 162801.4 & 3091.65 & 261.09 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 20039.61 & 486.66 & 191.05 & 120   & 0.01  & 9     & 5762.91 & 421.98 & 94.67 & 7.85  & 0.98  & 10    & 98.3  & 98    & 0 \\
    42    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 35387.13 & 841.33 & 280.35 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 10632.11 & 663.92 & 105.19 & 15.01 & 1     & 10    &       & 99.2  & 0 \\
    43    & 126.82 & 46.87 & 23.23 & 4.83  & 1     & 10    & 893.13 & 46.75 & 23.69 & 13.43 & 0.73  & 10    & 83.88 & 46.41 & 22.92 & 0.39  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 26.8  & 0 \\
    44    & 776.27 & 267.15 & 56.71 & 70.68 & 0.9   & 10    & 2594.25 & 94.38 & 45.88 & 34.64 & 0.54  & 10    & 308.5 & 95.75 & 44.68 & 0.82  & 1     & 10    & 10.1  & 45.6  & 0 \\
    45    & 8580.3 & 603.83 & 103.13 & 119.51 & 0.29  & 10    & 4744.14 & 143.29 & 70.63 & 58.59 & 0.48  & 10    & 1638.31 & 143.54 & 69.54 & 1.27  & 1     & 10    & 70.8  & 51.6  & 0 \\
    46    & 115330.2 & 858.76 & 183.74 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 11745.51 & 285.9 & 134.31 & 120   & 0.04  & 10    & 3143.97 & 273.64 & 89.4  & 2.89  & 0.99  & 10    & 98.7  & 94.7  & 0 \\
    47    & 218290.9 & 1854.24 & 240.12 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 25771.02 & 566.79 & 233.69 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 12096.36 & 513.36 & 122.23 & 8.32  & 0.99  & 10    & 99    & 97.8  & 0 \\
    48    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 44894.21 & 982.69 & 330.79 & 120   & 0     & 9     & 21762.33 & 818.55 & 134.71 & 23.86 & 0.97  & 10    &       & 99.56 & 0 \\
    49    & 181.14 & 52.26 & 27.66 & 7.38  & 1     & 10    & 1178.57 & 52.05 & 28.19 & 16.73 & 0.68  & 10    & 47.91 & 52.39 & 27.12 & 0.41  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 32.3  & 0 \\
    50    & 667.31 & 206.55 & 63.64 & 95.57 & 0.99  & 10    & 3215.4 & 105.25 & 54.35 & 40.1  & 0.53  & 10    & 564.64 & 105.48 & 54.16 & 0.9   & 1     & 10    & 0.5   & 47.2  & 0 \\
    51    & 15254.77 & 991.56 & 148.48 & 120   & 0.2   & 10    & 5784.69 & 158.59 & 86.59 & 66.52 & 0.47  & 10    & 2141.09 & 158.64 & 84.82 & 1.51  & 1     & 10    & 80.2  & 53    & 0 \\
    52    & 148647.5 & 634.21 & 300.65 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 13827.23 & 316.68 & 167.12 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 3512.3 & 302.49 & 109.7 & 3.97  & 0.98  & 10    & 98.4  & 95.9  & 0 \\
    53    & 342134.8 & 8155.96 & 498.39 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 28416.8 & 628.5 & 301.14 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 11457.42 & 564.85 & 149.1 & 22.96 & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 98.2  & 0 \\
    54    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 52209.36 & 1087.78 & 450.4 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 21870.32 & 893.92 & 168.85 & 31.04 & 1     & 10    &       & 99.9  & 0 \\
    55    & 58.42 & 58.55 & 28.61 & 13.09 & 1     & 10    & 1225.95 & 58.71 & 29.71 & 21.28 & 0.68  & 10    & 30.48 & 58.33 & 28.26 & 0.54  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 32.4  & 0 \\
    56    & 3236.62 & 506.39 & 82.16 & 107.06 & 0.63  & 10    & 3396.68 & 117.41 & 58.09 & 46.23 & 0.49  & 10    & 95.27 & 115.21 & 55.89 & 1.21  & 1     & 10    & 36.8  & 51    & 0 \\
    57    & 54135.56 & 1248.15 & 167.84 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 6020.57 & 176.57 & 89.37 & 77.96 & 0.42  & 10    & 1360.92 & 176.25 & 88.17 & 2.05  & 1     & 10    & 100   & 57.9  & 0 \\
    58    & 164765.5 & 1566.4 & 344.59 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 15110.99 & 350.79 & 179.68 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 2691.1 & 336.86 & 116.76 & 5.19  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.3  & 96.8  & 0 \\
    59    & 346991.2 & 12615.2 & 627.5 & 120   & 0     & 5     & 30836.4 & 698.59 & 329.33 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 10892.76 & 627.32 & 158.91 & 13.41 & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 98.3  & 0 \\
    60    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 55733 & 1205.65 & 485   & 120   & 0     & 9     & 20444.95 & 997.27 & 176.95 & 47.55 & 0.98  & 10    &       & 100   & 0 \\
    61    & 40.05 & 62.7  & 30.88 & 14.11 & 1     & 10    & 1481.92 & 62.8  & 31.72 & 21.03 & 0.64  & 10    & 14.31 & 62.68 & 30.76 & 0.52  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 35.6  & 0 \\
    62    & 3533.46 & 558.11 & 93.34 & 108.38 & 0.59  & 10    & 3695.23 & 128   & 61    & 49.69 & 0.47  & 10    & 13.27 & 126.14 & 58.56 & 1.21  & 1     & 10    & 41.4  & 52.6  & 0 \\
    63    & 53307.34 & 1517.76 & 192.17 & 120   & 0.16  & 10    & 6384.82 & 191.74 & 92.36 & 82.61 & 0.41  & 10    & 215.32 & 190.24 & 88.37 & 2.06  & 1     & 10    & 84.5  & 58.9  & 0 \\
    64    & 180909.2 & 1639.75 & 410.82 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 15414.22 & 380.08 & 186.18 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 1572.52 & 362.37 & 117.41 & 5.55  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 97.1  & 0 \\
    65    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 31509.53 & 757.4 & 336.69 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 8457.71 & 684.13 & 159.53 & 17.25 & 1     & 10    &       & 98.8  & 0 \\
    66    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 57011.58 & 1311.19 & 507.41 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 16481.25 & 1086.9 & 179.48 & 37.79 & 1     & 10    &       & 100   & 0 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently, your table overflows into the margins quite seriously, so I would say increasing the fonts size in order to allow for better readability is not an option, unless you decide do redesign the eniter table (probably by splitting it into three individual tables).

Comment: I see your point. But would you please let me know how I can move the table? Moreover, I truly appreciate it if you could help me with my other question. In meantime, I try to redesign the table. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the page number: Where exactly do you expect the page number? In the bottom of the landscape page, which would be equal to the right margin if you view the same page in portrait orientation? Wouldn't that be an odd place for a page number, expecially if you print the document?

Comment: a `tabular` is positioned exactly like a letter, if you put `\vspace*{-1cm}` before it it will move up acm and if you put `\hspace*{-1cm}`  begore it it will move to the left 1cm. (if you remove `\centering`)

Comment: also you may want to use `D` column from `dcolumn` or `S` column from `siunitx`  so that the numbers align on decimal points rather than use `l`.

Comment: @leandriis, I meant just below the table. Would it be odd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I did not decrease the margins, I wasn't able to increase the font size in your table while still making it sure, it did not exceed the available space. To nevertheless increase the readability, I added a bit of vertical white space every sixth row and aligned all numbers with respect to the decimal marker. Additionally, I used `longtable` to allow the table to occupy two pages and used horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package.

Here is how the first page of the table lookt like with the above mentioned changes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}
{
  \scriptsize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.5pt}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}S[table-format=2]
                      *{3}{S[table-format=6.2] 
                           S[table-format=4.2] 
                           S[table-format=3.2] 
                           S[table-format=3.2] 
                           S[table-format=1.2] 
                           S[table-format=2]} 
                      S[table-format=3.1] 
                      S[table-format=2.2] 
                      S[table-format=1.1]@{}}
  \caption{Comparison of the solution approaches based on the theoretical instances}\label{tab:addlabel}\\
    \toprule
    {\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Instance}}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Mathematical programming}  & \multicolumn{6}{c}{The NA-ACO algorithm}      & \multicolumn{6}{c}{The heuristic algorithm}   & {\multirow{3.5}{*}{\makecell{GAP1 \\ (\%)}}} & {\multirow{3.5}{*}{\makecell{GAP2 \\ (\%)}}} & {\multirow{3.5}{*}{\makecell{GAP3 \\ (\%)}}} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-13} \cmidrule(lr){14-19}
          & {Obj1}  & {Obj2}  & {Obj3}  & {\makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}} & {HPI}   & {FS\#} & {Obj1}  & {Obj2}  & {Obj3}  & {\makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}} & {HPI}   & {FS\#} & {Obj1}  & {Obj2}  & {Obj3}  & {\makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}} & {HPI}   & {FS\#}    &       &       &  \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
  \caption[]{Comparison of the solution approaches based on the theoretical instances - continued from previous page}\\
    \toprule
    {\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Instance}}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Mathematical programming}  & \multicolumn{6}{c}{The NA-ACO algorithm}      & \multicolumn{6}{c}{The heuristic algorithm}   & {\multirow{3.5}{*}{\makecell{GAP1 \\ (\%)}}} & {\multirow{3.5}{*}{\makecell{GAP2 \\ (\%)}}} & {\multirow{3.5}{*}{\makecell{GAP3 \\ (\%)}}} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-13} \cmidrule(lr){14-19}
          & {Obj1}  & {Obj2}  & {Obj3}  & {\makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}} & {HPI}   & {FS\#} & {Obj1}  & {Obj2}  & {Obj3}  & {\makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}} & {HPI}   & {FS\#} & {Obj1}  & {Obj2}  & {Obj3}  & {\makecell{CPUT \\ (min)}} & {HPI}   & {FS\#}    &       &       &  \\ \midrule
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
    1     & 0.18  & 5.21  & 2.02  & 0.85  & 1     & 10    & 0.39  & 5.08  & 2.03  & 0.03  & 1     & 10    & 0.62  & 5.2   & 2     & 0.13  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 0     & 0.3 \\
    2     & 0     & 10.7  & 4     & 0.1   & 1     & 10    & 3.68  & 11.03 & 4     & 3.9   & 1     & 10    & 1.54  & 10.8  & 4     & 0.17  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 0.1   & 0 \\
    3     & 14.6  & 16.6  & 6     & 0.81  & 1     & 10    & 104.38 & 16.53 & 6.02  & 6.35  & 0.93  & 10    & 17.65 & 16.73 & 6     & 0.18  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 7.2   & 0 \\
    4     & 1130.81 & 29.64 & 9.83  & 7.6   & 0.87  & 10    & 1093.3 & 31.3  & 10.11 & 11.73 & 0.79  & 10    & 883.42 & 29.33 & 9.43  & 0.29  & 0.97  & 10    & 12.3  & 20.4  & 2.3 \\
    5     & 4267.77 & 49    & 12.43 & 21.23 & 1     & 10    & 2892.79 & 60.62 & 13.41 & 24.4  & 0.28  & 10    & 2505.25 & 54.88 & 12.67 & 0.73  & 0.93  & 10    & 0     & 72    & 6.5 \\ 
    6     & 6966.24 & 72.12 & 13.33 & 38.91 & 0.9   & 10    & 4010.66 & 99.81 & 17.11 & 58.33 & 0.09  & 10    & 2121.39 & 84.26 & 13.67 & 2.14  & 0.97  & 10    & 9.7   & 90.7  & 3 \\ \addlinespace
    7     & 0.23  & 8.15  & 2.01  & 1.07  & 1     & 10    & 1.83  & 8.41  & 2.09  & 2.95  & 1     & 10    & 0.74  & 8.06  & 2     & 0.15  & 1     & 10    & 0.1   & 0.3   & 0.3 \\
    8     & 0.09  & 17.95 & 4.01  & 23.71 & 1     & 10    & 28.3  & 18.7  & 4.11  & 5.53  & 0.98  & 10    & 4.48  & 18.56 & 4     & 0.19  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 1.9   & 0.1 \\
    9     & 0.73  & 27.44 & 6.05  & 45.5  & 1     & 10    & 172.33 & 28.08 & 6.21  & 8.91  & 0.92  & 10    & 5.78  & 27.81 & 6     & 0.26  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 8.2   & 0 \\
    10    & 284.61 & 79.82 & 12.52 & 77.59 & 1     & 10    & 940.89 & 55.86 & 12.43 & 17.31 & 0.76  & 10    & 354.36 & 54.09 & 12    & 0.46  & 1     & 10    & 0.1   & 24.2  & 0 \\
    11    & 18594.44 & 129.64 & 15.99 & 77.27 & 0     & 10    & 2894.15 & 106.75 & 17.98 & 42.97 & 0.18  & 10    & 720.47 & 94.73 & 13.11 & 0.84  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.1  & 80.7  & 0 \\
    12    & 46281.17 & 179.85 & 17.63 & 91.87 & 0     & 10    & 5530.74 & 178   & 21.76 & 77.68 & 0.07  & 10    & 1558.86 & 144.23 & 14.24 & 1.26  & 0.99  & 10    & 98.9  & 91.6  & 0 \\ \addlinespace
    13    & 7.54  & 13.61 & 2.09  & 12.68 & 1     & 10    & 20.77 & 14.23 & 2.52  & 4.07  & 0.95  & 10    & 6.96  & 13.98 & 2.06  & 0.19  & 0.98  & 10    & 0     & 4.2   & 1.9 \\
    14    & 744.81 & 50.74 & 5.14  & 64.83 & 0.63  & 10    & 343.69 & 28.7  & 5.51  & 8.16  & 0.79  & 10    & 92.07 & 27.15 & 4.85  & 0.35  & 0.99  & 10    & 36.2  & 19.9  & 0 \\
    15    & 1531.39 & 87.71 & 8.65  & 73.33 & 0.19  & 10    & 548.69 & 44.34 & 8.06  & 12.54 & 0.74  & 10    & 134.05 & 42.57 & 6.62  & 0.56  & 1     & 10    & 81.1  & 26    & 0 \\ 
    16    & 15248.51 & 170.71 & 23.32 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 1765.9 & 88.19 & 17.06 & 26.81 & 0.41  & 10    & 428.31 & 84.39 & 13.19 & 4.47  & 1     & 10    & 99.5  & 59    & 0 \\
    17    & 32220.52 & 308.6 & 22.36 & 115.42 & 0     & 10    & 3981.8 & 172.64 & 25.69 & 72.12 & 0.11  & 10    & 548.17 & 146.81 & 15.29 & 1.29  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.5  & 88    & 0 \\
    18    & 6091.59 & 1017.26 & 22.08 & 120   & 0.07  & 10    & 7420.12 & 287.26 & 32.11 & 120   & 0.04  & 10    & 843.87 & 219.56 & 16.28 & 2.53  & 1     & 10    & 92.7  & 95.6  & 0 \\ \addlinespace
    19    & 53.38 & 19.77 & 7.5   & 2.68  & 1     & 10    & 111.41 & 19.71 & 7.29  & 5.49  & 0.96  & 10    & 44.14 & 19.95 & 7.51  & 0.23  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 3.8   & 0.1 \\
    20    & 215.55 & 38.87 & 15.24 & 15    & 1     & 10    & 651.13 & 38.6  & 15.47 & 11.84 & 0.78  & 10    & 182.17 & 38.11 & 15.11 & 0.33  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 21.8  & 0 \\
    21    & 567.37 & 60.71 & 23.34 & 48.1  & 1     & 10    & 1362.5 & 58.11 & 23.56 & 19.33 & 0.69  & 10    & 521.92 & 57.75 & 22.67 & 0.46  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 31    & 0 \\
    22    & 10838.22 & 327.13 & 51.96 & 120   & 0.2   & 10    & 2122.57 & 115.9 & 46.17 & 46.43 & 0.57  & 10    & 1347.86 & 114.95 & 45.36 & 1.02  & 1     & 10    & 80.1  & 42.7  & 0 \\
    23    & 57412.46 & 653.81 & 65.43 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 9046.97 & 231.64 & 77.07 & 116.57 & 0.05  & 10    & 3521.58 & 198.79 & 43.58 & 2.17  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.1  & 94.1  & 0 \\
    24    & 179789.2 & 885.03 & 92.67 & 120   & 0     & 9     & 15808.37 & 401.1 & 104.74 & 120   & 0.02  & 9     & 6025.15 & 334.02 & 48.43 & 6.04  & 0.98  & 10    & 99.11 & 97.11 & 0 \\ \addlinespace
    25    & 19.94 & 24.13 & 8.27  & 4.63  & 1     & 10    & 110   & 24.28 & 8.44  & 6.71  & 0.92  & 10    & 7.44  & 24.3  & 8.24  & 0.26  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 7.8   & 0.1 \\
    26    & 101.52 & 48.45 & 16.71 & 52.98 & 1     & 10    & 782.48 & 48.92 & 17.4  & 16.34 & 0.74  & 10    & 77.16 & 49.35 & 16.78 & 0.41  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 26.2  & 0 \\
    27    & 2123.34 & 202.67 & 31.71 & 97.49 & 0.53  & 10    & 1586.7 & 74.26 & 26.7  & 27.12 & 0.6   & 10    & 245.94 & 75.41 & 25.65 & 0.61  & 1     & 10    & 46.6  & 40.4  & 0 \\
    28    & 39675.55 & 661.02 & 72.95 & 120   & 0.08  & 10    & 3990.52 & 153   & 51.41 & 61.91 & 0.5   & 10    & 1673.7 & 152.8 & 50    & 1.34  & 1     & 10    & 92.2  & 50.4  & 0 \\
    29    & 111545.7 & 989.78 & 98.33 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 10387.34 & 301.18 & 92.98 & 120   & 0.03  & 10    & 2303.83 & 261.1 & 47.56 & 2.9   & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 95.8  & 0 \\
    30    & 168626.5 & 1288.31 & 144.81 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 18672.19 & 517.85 & 130.56 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 3422.09 & 399.08 & 51.87 & 12.62 & 1     & 10    & 99.8  & 98.7  & 0 \\ \addlinespace
    31    & 22.44 & 30.16 & 15.84 & 2.27  & 1     & 10    & 400.31 & 30.15 & 16.08 & 10.16 & 0.82  & 10    & 16.39 & 30.08 & 16.17 & 0.58  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 18    & 0 \\
    32    & 499   & 63.68 & 31.74 & 36.05 & 1     & 10    & 1514.82 & 61.12 & 30.35 & 20.58 & 0.69  & 10    & 230.41 & 63.12 & 32.05 & 0.96  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 31.3  & 0 \\
    33    & 1640.16 & 114.15 & 50.84 & 80.09 & 1     & 10    & 2977.32 & 91.89 & 47.89 & 32.54 & 0.61  & 10    & 1681.3 & 92.09 & 47.48 & 1.48  & 1     & 10    & 0.1   & 39.2  & 0 \\
    34    & 43656.29 & 912.92 & 115.96 & 120   & 0.4   & 10    & 7131.83 & 182.45 & 94.76 & 86.22 & 0.54  & 10    & 5276.55 & 183.18 & 93.82 & 3.86  & 1     & 10    & 60    & 46    & 0 \\
    35    & 172934.4 & 1285.11 & 178.8 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 16635.11 & 365.36 & 165.6 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 4371.41 & 314.36 & 84.42 & 4.69  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.1  & 97.4  & 0 \\
    36    & 252501.2 & 2665.97 & 258.28 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 29705.14 & 633.69 & 247.07 & 120   & 0.01  & 9     & 8521.68 & 496.41 & 95.59 & 12.53 & 0.97  & 10    & 97.4  & 98.89 & 0 \\ \addlinespace
    37    & 0.39  & 39.72 & 17.41 & 3.28  & 1     & 10    & 551.69 & 39.75 & 17.88 & 15.17 & 0.77  & 10    & 12.21 & 39.49 & 17.34 & 0.38  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 23.2  & 0 \\
    38    & 289.29 & 155.34 & 38.45 & 74.93 & 0.99  & 10    & 1831.96 & 81.32 & 36.12 & 28.48 & 0.59  & 10    & 61.39 & 80.13 & 35.35 & 0.73  & 1     & 10    & 1.4   & 40.6  & 0 \\
    39    & 8222.3 & 752.47 & 97.57 & 118.37 & 0.28  & 10    & 3361.03 & 123.06 & 53.84 & 49.36 & 0.5   & 10    & 236.44 & 121.68 & 51.58 & 1.15  & 1     & 10    & 71.7  & 49.8  & 0 \\
    40    & 50211.12 & 1762.58 & 143.8 & 119.87 & 0     & 10    & 9195.09 & 246.92 & 108.61 & 119.97 & 0.05  & 10    & 1215.26 & 231.84 & 70.89 & 2.47  & 1     & 10    & 99.6  & 95    & 0 \\
    41    & 162801.4 & 3091.65 & 261.09 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 20039.61 & 486.66 & 191.05 & 120   & 0.01  & 9     & 5762.91 & 421.98 & 94.67 & 7.85  & 0.98  & 10    & 98.3  & 98    & 0 \\
    42    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 35387.13 & 841.33 & 280.35 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 10632.11 & 663.92 & 105.19 & 15.01 & 1     & 10    &       & 99.2  & 0 \\ \addlinespace
    43    & 126.82 & 46.87 & 23.23 & 4.83  & 1     & 10    & 893.13 & 46.75 & 23.69 & 13.43 & 0.73  & 10    & 83.88 & 46.41 & 22.92 & 0.39  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 26.8  & 0 \\
    44    & 776.27 & 267.15 & 56.71 & 70.68 & 0.9   & 10    & 2594.25 & 94.38 & 45.88 & 34.64 & 0.54  & 10    & 308.5 & 95.75 & 44.68 & 0.82  & 1     & 10    & 10.1  & 45.6  & 0 \\
    45    & 8580.3 & 603.83 & 103.13 & 119.51 & 0.29  & 10    & 4744.14 & 143.29 & 70.63 & 58.59 & 0.48  & 10    & 1638.31 & 143.54 & 69.54 & 1.27  & 1     & 10    & 70.8  & 51.6  & 0 \\
    46    & 115330.2 & 858.76 & 183.74 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 11745.51 & 285.9 & 134.31 & 120   & 0.04  & 10    & 3143.97 & 273.64 & 89.4  & 2.89  & 0.99  & 10    & 98.7  & 94.7  & 0 \\
    47    & 218290.9 & 1854.24 & 240.12 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 25771.02 & 566.79 & 233.69 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 12096.36 & 513.36 & 122.23 & 8.32  & 0.99  & 10    & 99    & 97.8  & 0 \\
    48    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 44894.21 & 982.69 & 330.79 & 120   & 0     & 9     & 21762.33 & 818.55 & 134.71 & 23.86 & 0.97  & 10    &       & 99.56 & 0 \\ \addlinespace
    49    & 181.14 & 52.26 & 27.66 & 7.38  & 1     & 10    & 1178.57 & 52.05 & 28.19 & 16.73 & 0.68  & 10    & 47.91 & 52.39 & 27.12 & 0.41  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 32.3  & 0 \\
    50    & 667.31 & 206.55 & 63.64 & 95.57 & 0.99  & 10    & 3215.4 & 105.25 & 54.35 & 40.1  & 0.53  & 10    & 564.64 & 105.48 & 54.16 & 0.9   & 1     & 10    & 0.5   & 47.2  & 0 \\
    51    & 15254.77 & 991.56 & 148.48 & 120   & 0.2   & 10    & 5784.69 & 158.59 & 86.59 & 66.52 & 0.47  & 10    & 2141.09 & 158.64 & 84.82 & 1.51  & 1     & 10    & 80.2  & 53    & 0 \\
    52    & 148647.5 & 634.21 & 300.65 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 13827.23 & 316.68 & 167.12 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 3512.3 & 302.49 & 109.7 & 3.97  & 0.98  & 10    & 98.4  & 95.9  & 0 \\
    53    & 342134.8 & 8155.96 & 498.39 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 28416.8 & 628.5 & 301.14 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 11457.42 & 564.85 & 149.1 & 22.96 & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 98.2  & 0 \\
    54    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 52209.36 & 1087.78 & 450.4 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 21870.32 & 893.92 & 168.85 & 31.04 & 1     & 10    &       & 99.9  & 0 \\ \addlinespace
    55    & 58.42 & 58.55 & 28.61 & 13.09 & 1     & 10    & 1225.95 & 58.71 & 29.71 & 21.28 & 0.68  & 10    & 30.48 & 58.33 & 28.26 & 0.54  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 32.4  & 0 \\
    56    & 3236.62 & 506.39 & 82.16 & 107.06 & 0.63  & 10    & 3396.68 & 117.41 & 58.09 & 46.23 & 0.49  & 10    & 95.27 & 115.21 & 55.89 & 1.21  & 1     & 10    & 36.8  & 51    & 0 \\
    57    & 54135.56 & 1248.15 & 167.84 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 6020.57 & 176.57 & 89.37 & 77.96 & 0.42  & 10    & 1360.92 & 176.25 & 88.17 & 2.05  & 1     & 10    & 100   & 57.9  & 0 \\
    58    & 164765.5 & 1566.4 & 344.59 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 15110.99 & 350.79 & 179.68 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 2691.1 & 336.86 & 116.76 & 5.19  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.3  & 96.8  & 0 \\
    59    & 346991.2 & 12615.2 & 627.5 & 120   & 0     & 5     & 30836.4 & 698.59 & 329.33 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 10892.76 & 627.32 & 158.91 & 13.41 & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 98.3  & 0 \\
    60    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 55733 & 1205.65 & 485   & 120   & 0     & 9     & 20444.95 & 997.27 & 176.95 & 47.55 & 0.98  & 10    &       & 100   & 0 \\ \addlinespace
    61    & 40.05 & 62.7  & 30.88 & 14.11 & 1     & 10    & 1481.92 & 62.8  & 31.72 & 21.03 & 0.64  & 10    & 14.31 & 62.68 & 30.76 & 0.52  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 35.6  & 0 \\
    62    & 3533.46 & 558.11 & 93.34 & 108.38 & 0.59  & 10    & 3695.23 & 128   & 61    & 49.69 & 0.47  & 10    & 13.27 & 126.14 & 58.56 & 1.21  & 1     & 10    & 41.4  & 52.6  & 0 \\
    63    & 53307.34 & 1517.76 & 192.17 & 120   & 0.16  & 10    & 6384.82 & 191.74 & 92.36 & 82.61 & 0.41  & 10    & 215.32 & 190.24 & 88.37 & 2.06  & 1     & 10    & 84.5  & 58.9  & 0 \\
    64    & 180909.2 & 1639.75 & 410.82 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 15414.22 & 380.08 & 186.18 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 1572.52 & 362.37 & 117.41 & 5.55  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 97.1  & 0 \\
    65    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 31509.53 & 757.4 & 336.69 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 8457.71 & 684.13 & 159.53 & 17.25 & 1     & 10    &       & 98.8  & 0 \\
    66    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 57011.58 & 1311.19 & 507.41 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 16481.25 & 1086.9 & 179.48 & 37.79 & 1     & 10    &       & 100   & 0 \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}%
    }
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not only is your table currently too wide, it's also much too long to fit on a single (landscape) page. I would like to suggest that you employ a `longtable` environment, reduce the amount of inter-column whitespace by 50% or more, and use a `\small` relative font size. To improve readability, I'd also add a bit of whitespace every 5 or so rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set text block size suitably
\usepackage{multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textheight}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt} % default: 6pt
\small
\begin{longtable}{@{} r | *{3}{llllll|} lll @{}} % 22 columns in all
\caption{Comparison of solution approaches based on theoretical instances}
\label{tab:addlabel} \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Inst.}} & 
\multicolumn{6}{l|}{Mathematical programming}  & 
\multicolumn{6}{l|}{The NA-ACO algorithm}      & 
\multicolumn{6}{l|}{The heuristic algorithm}   & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP1 \\ (\%)}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP2 \\ (\%)}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP3 \\ (\%)}} \\ 
\cline{2-19}
& Obj1  & Obj2  & Obj3  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)} & HPI   & FS\#  
& Obj1  & Obj2  & Obj3  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)} & HPI   & FS\#  
& Obj1  & Obj2  & Obj3  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)} & HPI   & FS\#  
&       &       &  \\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead


\multicolumn{22}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, cont'd} \\[1ex]
\hline
\multirow{3.5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Inst.}} & 
\multicolumn{6}{l|}{Mathematical programming}  & 
\multicolumn{6}{l|}{The NA-ACO algorithm}      & 
\multicolumn{6}{l|}{The heuristic algorithm}   & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP1 \\ (\%)}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP2 \\ (\%)}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{GAP3 \\ (\%)}} \\ 
\cline{2-19}
& Obj1  & Obj2  & Obj3  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)} & HPI   & FS\#  
& Obj1  & Obj2  & Obj3  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)} & HPI   & FS\#  
& Obj1  & Obj2  & Obj3  & \makecell{CPUT \\ (min)} & HPI   & FS\#  
&       &       &  \\ 
\hline
\endhead


\hline
\multicolumn{22}{r@{}}{\em cont'd on following page}\\
\endfoot


\hline
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
    1     & 0.18  & 5.21  & 2.02  & 0.85  & 1     & 10    & 0.39  & 5.08  & 2.03  & 0.03  & 1     & 10    & 0.62  & 5.2   & 2     & 0.13  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 0     & 0.3 \\
    2     & 0     & 10.7  & 4     & 0.1   & 1     & 10    & 3.68  & 11.03 & 4     & 3.9   & 1     & 10    & 1.54  & 10.8  & 4     & 0.17  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 0.1   & 0 \\
    3     & 14.6  & 16.6  & 6     & 0.81  & 1     & 10    & 104.38 & 16.53 & 6.02  & 6.35  & 0.93  & 10    & 17.65 & 16.73 & 6     & 0.18  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 7.2   & 0 \\
    4     & 1130.81 & 29.64 & 9.83  & 7.6   & 0.87  & 10    & 1093.3 & 31.3  & 10.11 & 11.73 & 0.79  & 10    & 883.42 & 29.33 & 9.43  & 0.29  & 0.97  & 10    & 12.3  & 20.4  & 2.3 \\
    5     & 4267.77 & 49    & 12.43 & 21.23 & 1     & 10    & 2892.79 & 60.62 & 13.41 & 24.4  & 0.28  & 10    & 2505.25 & 54.88 & 12.67 & 0.73  & 0.93  & 10    & 0     & 72    & 6.5 \\[1ex]
    6     & 6966.24 & 72.12 & 13.33 & 38.91 & 0.9   & 10    & 4010.66 & 99.81 & 17.11 & 58.33 & 0.09  & 10    & 2121.39 & 84.26 & 13.67 & 2.14  & 0.97  & 10    & 9.7   & 90.7  & 3 \\
    7     & 0.23  & 8.15  & 2.01  & 1.07  & 1     & 10    & 1.83  & 8.41  & 2.09  & 2.95  & 1     & 10    & 0.74  & 8.06  & 2     & 0.15  & 1     & 10    & 0.1   & 0.3   & 0.3 \\
    8     & 0.09  & 17.95 & 4.01  & 23.71 & 1     & 10    & 28.3  & 18.7  & 4.11  & 5.53  & 0.98  & 10    & 4.48  & 18.56 & 4     & 0.19  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 1.9   & 0.1 \\
    9     & 0.73  & 27.44 & 6.05  & 45.5  & 1     & 10    & 172.33 & 28.08 & 6.21  & 8.91  & 0.92  & 10    & 5.78  & 27.81 & 6     & 0.26  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 8.2   & 0 \\
    10    & 284.61 & 79.82 & 12.52 & 77.59 & 1     & 10    & 940.89 & 55.86 & 12.43 & 17.31 & 0.76  & 10    & 354.36 & 54.09 & 12    & 0.46  & 1     & 10    & 0.1   & 24.2  & 0 \\[1ex]
    11    & 18594.44 & 129.64 & 15.99 & 77.27 & 0     & 10    & 2894.15 & 106.75 & 17.98 & 42.97 & 0.18  & 10    & 720.47 & 94.73 & 13.11 & 0.84  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.1  & 80.7  & 0 \\
    12    & 46281.17 & 179.85 & 17.63 & 91.87 & 0     & 10    & 5530.74 & 178   & 21.76 & 77.68 & 0.07  & 10    & 1558.86 & 144.23 & 14.24 & 1.26  & 0.99  & 10    & 98.9  & 91.6  & 0 \\
    13    & 7.54  & 13.61 & 2.09  & 12.68 & 1     & 10    & 20.77 & 14.23 & 2.52  & 4.07  & 0.95  & 10    & 6.96  & 13.98 & 2.06  & 0.19  & 0.98  & 10    & 0     & 4.2   & 1.9 \\
    14    & 744.81 & 50.74 & 5.14  & 64.83 & 0.63  & 10    & 343.69 & 28.7  & 5.51  & 8.16  & 0.79  & 10    & 92.07 & 27.15 & 4.85  & 0.35  & 0.99  & 10    & 36.2  & 19.9  & 0 \\
    15    & 1531.39 & 87.71 & 8.65  & 73.33 & 0.19  & 10    & 548.69 & 44.34 & 8.06  & 12.54 & 0.74  & 10    & 134.05 & 42.57 & 6.62  & 0.56  & 1     & 10    & 81.1  & 26    & 0 \\[1ex]
    16    & 15248.51 & 170.71 & 23.32 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 1765.9 & 88.19 & 17.06 & 26.81 & 0.41  & 10    & 428.31 & 84.39 & 13.19 & 4.47  & 1     & 10    & 99.5  & 59    & 0 \\
    17    & 32220.52 & 308.6 & 22.36 & 115.42 & 0     & 10    & 3981.8 & 172.64 & 25.69 & 72.12 & 0.11  & 10    & 548.17 & 146.81 & 15.29 & 1.29  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.5  & 88    & 0 \\
    18    & 6091.59 & 1017.26 & 22.08 & 120   & 0.07  & 10    & 7420.12 & 287.26 & 32.11 & 120   & 0.04  & 10    & 843.87 & 219.56 & 16.28 & 2.53  & 1     & 10    & 92.7  & 95.6  & 0 \\
    19    & 53.38 & 19.77 & 7.5   & 2.68  & 1     & 10    & 111.41 & 19.71 & 7.29  & 5.49  & 0.96  & 10    & 44.14 & 19.95 & 7.51  & 0.23  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 3.8   & 0.1 \\
    20    & 215.55 & 38.87 & 15.24 & 15    & 1     & 10    & 651.13 & 38.6  & 15.47 & 11.84 & 0.78  & 10    & 182.17 & 38.11 & 15.11 & 0.33  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 21.8  & 0 \\[1ex]
    21    & 567.37 & 60.71 & 23.34 & 48.1  & 1     & 10    & 1362.5 & 58.11 & 23.56 & 19.33 & 0.69  & 10    & 521.92 & 57.75 & 22.67 & 0.46  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 31    & 0 \\
    22    & 10838.22 & 327.13 & 51.96 & 120   & 0.2   & 10    & 2122.57 & 115.9 & 46.17 & 46.43 & 0.57  & 10    & 1347.86 & 114.95 & 45.36 & 1.02  & 1     & 10    & 80.1  & 42.7  & 0 \\
    23    & 57412.46 & 653.81 & 65.43 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 9046.97 & 231.64 & 77.07 & 116.57 & 0.05  & 10    & 3521.58 & 198.79 & 43.58 & 2.17  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.1  & 94.1  & 0 \\
    24    & 179789.2 & 885.03 & 92.67 & 120   & 0     & 9     & 15808.37 & 401.1 & 104.74 & 120   & 0.02  & 9     & 6025.15 & 334.02 & 48.43 & 6.04  & 0.98  & 10    & 99.11 & 97.11 & 0 \\
    25    & 19.94 & 24.13 & 8.27  & 4.63  & 1     & 10    & 110   & 24.28 & 8.44  & 6.71  & 0.92  & 10    & 7.44  & 24.3  & 8.24  & 0.26  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 7.8   & 0.1 \\[1ex]
    26    & 101.52 & 48.45 & 16.71 & 52.98 & 1     & 10    & 782.48 & 48.92 & 17.4  & 16.34 & 0.74  & 10    & 77.16 & 49.35 & 16.78 & 0.41  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 26.2  & 0 \\
    27    & 2123.34 & 202.67 & 31.71 & 97.49 & 0.53  & 10    & 1586.7 & 74.26 & 26.7  & 27.12 & 0.6   & 10    & 245.94 & 75.41 & 25.65 & 0.61  & 1     & 10    & 46.6  & 40.4  & 0 \\
    28    & 39675.55 & 661.02 & 72.95 & 120   & 0.08  & 10    & 3990.52 & 153   & 51.41 & 61.91 & 0.5   & 10    & 1673.7 & 152.8 & 50    & 1.34  & 1     & 10    & 92.2  & 50.4  & 0 \\
    29    & 111545.7 & 989.78 & 98.33 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 10387.34 & 301.18 & 92.98 & 120   & 0.03  & 10    & 2303.83 & 261.1 & 47.56 & 2.9   & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 95.8  & 0 \\
    30    & 168626.5 & 1288.31 & 144.81 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 18672.19 & 517.85 & 130.56 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 3422.09 & 399.08 & 51.87 & 12.62 & 1     & 10    & 99.8  & 98.7  & 0 \\[1ex]
    31    & 22.44 & 30.16 & 15.84 & 2.27  & 1     & 10    & 400.31 & 30.15 & 16.08 & 10.16 & 0.82  & 10    & 16.39 & 30.08 & 16.17 & 0.58  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 18    & 0 \\
    32    & 499   & 63.68 & 31.74 & 36.05 & 1     & 10    & 1514.82 & 61.12 & 30.35 & 20.58 & 0.69  & 10    & 230.41 & 63.12 & 32.05 & 0.96  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 31.3  & 0 \\
    33    & 1640.16 & 114.15 & 50.84 & 80.09 & 1     & 10    & 2977.32 & 91.89 & 47.89 & 32.54 & 0.61  & 10    & 1681.3 & 92.09 & 47.48 & 1.48  & 1     & 10    & 0.1   & 39.2  & 0 \\
    34    & 43656.29 & 912.92 & 115.96 & 120   & 0.4   & 10    & 7131.83 & 182.45 & 94.76 & 86.22 & 0.54  & 10    & 5276.55 & 183.18 & 93.82 & 3.86  & 1     & 10    & 60    & 46    & 0 \\
    35    & 172934.4 & 1285.11 & 178.8 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 16635.11 & 365.36 & 165.6 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 4371.41 & 314.36 & 84.42 & 4.69  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.1  & 97.4  & 0 \\[1ex]
    36    & 252501.2 & 2665.97 & 258.28 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 29705.14 & 633.69 & 247.07 & 120   & 0.01  & 9     & 8521.68 & 496.41 & 95.59 & 12.53 & 0.97  & 10    & 97.4  & 98.89 & 0 \\
    37    & 0.39  & 39.72 & 17.41 & 3.28  & 1     & 10    & 551.69 & 39.75 & 17.88 & 15.17 & 0.77  & 10    & 12.21 & 39.49 & 17.34 & 0.38  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 23.2  & 0 \\
    38    & 289.29 & 155.34 & 38.45 & 74.93 & 0.99  & 10    & 1831.96 & 81.32 & 36.12 & 28.48 & 0.59  & 10    & 61.39 & 80.13 & 35.35 & 0.73  & 1     & 10    & 1.4   & 40.6  & 0 \\
    39    & 8222.3 & 752.47 & 97.57 & 118.37 & 0.28  & 10    & 3361.03 & 123.06 & 53.84 & 49.36 & 0.5   & 10    & 236.44 & 121.68 & 51.58 & 1.15  & 1     & 10    & 71.7  & 49.8  & 0 \\
    40    & 50211.12 & 1762.58 & 143.8 & 119.87 & 0     & 10    & 9195.09 & 246.92 & 108.61 & 119.97 & 0.05  & 10    & 1215.26 & 231.84 & 70.89 & 2.47  & 1     & 10    & 99.6  & 95    & 0 \\[1ex]
    41    & 162801.4 & 3091.65 & 261.09 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 20039.61 & 486.66 & 191.05 & 120   & 0.01  & 9     & 5762.91 & 421.98 & 94.67 & 7.85  & 0.98  & 10    & 98.3  & 98    & 0 \\
    42    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 35387.13 & 841.33 & 280.35 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 10632.11 & 663.92 & 105.19 & 15.01 & 1     & 10    &       & 99.2  & 0 \\
    43    & 126.82 & 46.87 & 23.23 & 4.83  & 1     & 10    & 893.13 & 46.75 & 23.69 & 13.43 & 0.73  & 10    & 83.88 & 46.41 & 22.92 & 0.39  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 26.8  & 0 \\
    44    & 776.27 & 267.15 & 56.71 & 70.68 & 0.9   & 10    & 2594.25 & 94.38 & 45.88 & 34.64 & 0.54  & 10    & 308.5 & 95.75 & 44.68 & 0.82  & 1     & 10    & 10.1  & 45.6  & 0 \\
    45    & 8580.3 & 603.83 & 103.13 & 119.51 & 0.29  & 10    & 4744.14 & 143.29 & 70.63 & 58.59 & 0.48  & 10    & 1638.31 & 143.54 & 69.54 & 1.27  & 1     & 10    & 70.8  & 51.6  & 0 \\[1ex]
    46    & 115330.2 & 858.76 & 183.74 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 11745.51 & 285.9 & 134.31 & 120   & 0.04  & 10    & 3143.97 & 273.64 & 89.4  & 2.89  & 0.99  & 10    & 98.7  & 94.7  & 0 \\
    47    & 218290.9 & 1854.24 & 240.12 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 25771.02 & 566.79 & 233.69 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 12096.36 & 513.36 & 122.23 & 8.32  & 0.99  & 10    & 99    & 97.8  & 0 \\
    48    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 44894.21 & 982.69 & 330.79 & 120   & 0     & 9     & 21762.33 & 818.55 & 134.71 & 23.86 & 0.97  & 10    &       & 99.56 & 0 \\
    49    & 181.14 & 52.26 & 27.66 & 7.38  & 1     & 10    & 1178.57 & 52.05 & 28.19 & 16.73 & 0.68  & 10    & 47.91 & 52.39 & 27.12 & 0.41  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 32.3  & 0 \\
    50    & 667.31 & 206.55 & 63.64 & 95.57 & 0.99  & 10    & 3215.4 & 105.25 & 54.35 & 40.1  & 0.53  & 10    & 564.64 & 105.48 & 54.16 & 0.9   & 1     & 10    & 0.5   & 47.2  & 0 \\[1ex]
    51    & 15254.77 & 991.56 & 148.48 & 120   & 0.2   & 10    & 5784.69 & 158.59 & 86.59 & 66.52 & 0.47  & 10    & 2141.09 & 158.64 & 84.82 & 1.51  & 1     & 10    & 80.2  & 53    & 0 \\
    52    & 148647.5 & 634.21 & 300.65 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 13827.23 & 316.68 & 167.12 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 3512.3 & 302.49 & 109.7 & 3.97  & 0.98  & 10    & 98.4  & 95.9  & 0 \\
    53    & 342134.8 & 8155.96 & 498.39 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 28416.8 & 628.5 & 301.14 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 11457.42 & 564.85 & 149.1 & 22.96 & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 98.2  & 0 \\
    54    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 52209.36 & 1087.78 & 450.4 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 21870.32 & 893.92 & 168.85 & 31.04 & 1     & 10    &       & 99.9  & 0 \\
    55    & 58.42 & 58.55 & 28.61 & 13.09 & 1     & 10    & 1225.95 & 58.71 & 29.71 & 21.28 & 0.68  & 10    & 30.48 & 58.33 & 28.26 & 0.54  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 32.4  & 0 \\[1ex]
    56    & 3236.62 & 506.39 & 82.16 & 107.06 & 0.63  & 10    & 3396.68 & 117.41 & 58.09 & 46.23 & 0.49  & 10    & 95.27 & 115.21 & 55.89 & 1.21  & 1     & 10    & 36.8  & 51    & 0 \\
    57    & 54135.56 & 1248.15 & 167.84 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 6020.57 & 176.57 & 89.37 & 77.96 & 0.42  & 10    & 1360.92 & 176.25 & 88.17 & 2.05  & 1     & 10    & 100   & 57.9  & 0 \\
    58    & 164765.5 & 1566.4 & 344.59 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 15110.99 & 350.79 & 179.68 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 2691.1 & 336.86 & 116.76 & 5.19  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.3  & 96.8  & 0 \\
    59    & 346991.2 & 12615.2 & 627.5 & 120   & 0     & 5     & 30836.4 & 698.59 & 329.33 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 10892.76 & 627.32 & 158.91 & 13.41 & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 98.3  & 0 \\
    60    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 55733 & 1205.65 & 485   & 120   & 0     & 9     & 20444.95 & 997.27 & 176.95 & 47.55 & 0.98  & 10    &       & 100   & 0 \\[1ex]
    61    & 40.05 & 62.7  & 30.88 & 14.11 & 1     & 10    & 1481.92 & 62.8  & 31.72 & 21.03 & 0.64  & 10    & 14.31 & 62.68 & 30.76 & 0.52  & 1     & 10    & 0     & 35.6  & 0 \\
    62    & 3533.46 & 558.11 & 93.34 & 108.38 & 0.59  & 10    & 3695.23 & 128   & 61    & 49.69 & 0.47  & 10    & 13.27 & 126.14 & 58.56 & 1.21  & 1     & 10    & 41.4  & 52.6  & 0 \\
    63    & 53307.34 & 1517.76 & 192.17 & 120   & 0.16  & 10    & 6384.82 & 191.74 & 92.36 & 82.61 & 0.41  & 10    & 215.32 & 190.24 & 88.37 & 2.06  & 1     & 10    & 84.5  & 58.9  & 0 \\
    64    & 180909.2 & 1639.75 & 410.82 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 15414.22 & 380.08 & 186.18 & 120   & 0.02  & 10    & 1572.52 & 362.37 & 117.41 & 5.55  & 0.99  & 10    & 99.2  & 97.1  & 0 \\
    65    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 31509.53 & 757.4 & 336.69 & 120   & 0.01  & 10    & 8457.71 & 684.13 & 159.53 & 17.25 & 1     & 10    &       & 98.8  & 0 \\
    66    &       &       &       &       &       & 0     & 57011.58 & 1311.19 & 507.41 & 120   & 0     & 10    & 16481.25 & 1086.9 & 179.48 & 37.79 & 1     & 10    &       & 100   & 0 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```